# Spring 6.0.0 doesn't support Apache Tiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I've been using the `Spring 5.7.x` (through the `Spring boot 2.7.6`) with `Apache Tiles 3`. I'm now about to migrate my application to the recently released latest version of `Spring 6.0.0` (through `Spring boot 3.0.0`) and I realized during the migration that - TilesConfigurer class has been removed completely.

I can't find any official resource and this class has **never** been deprecated so I'm not sure why the entire tiles view package (org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3) is missing in the latest Spring 6.0.x version as per the documentation here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html

Does anyone know the reason for it?

Comment: Spring Boot 3 needs min Java17 and Jakarta EE 9. You can not mix JavaEE and JakartaEE packages. Last package is 3.0.8 from 2017 and used javax, so it is not compatible with Jakarta and SpringBoot3.
Read it: https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0

Comment: Hi @Numichi - I'm not referring to the Jave EE here. Tiles is an Apache package and it has the compatibility with Spring Boot 2.x and why suddenly this support is dropped in Spring Boot 3?

Comment: And seeing as Apache Tiles has been retired to the attic (see https://attic.apache.org/projects/tiles.html), I doubt you will get a newer version that support Jakarta EE 9.

Comment: @SanthoshReddyMandadi Tiles uses the servlet and JSP APIs, and these are definitely part of Java EE.

Comment: Ah.. makes sense! So, this might be the reason for this support being dropped. But there has been no mention of dropping this package surprisingly in the documentation or release notes from Spring, weird. Thanks @Numichi and Rob

Comment: @SanthoshReddyMandadi Were you able to find a workaround to replace the TilesConfigurer with spring 6? I am kind of stuck on how to replace the already present code to configure tiles using TilesConfigurer bean.